# How to draw two horizontal lines for the layout(top and bottom) in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to draw two horizontal lines to the layout.One line want to be at the top and the second one should want to be at the bottom.

How to achieve this?

Thanks for you precious time..

Comment: draw means what you want to do. is it just a line, or you want to paint on layout.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i need to create a two lines in the layout,one should want to be at the top and the other one want to be at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, it will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/white" >

   <View  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_height="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/black" />
   <View  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="2dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

Method1

Use a relative layout. You can define other ui elements also. Have View with a specified height and place it at the top and the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" // specify a number in dp to increase or decrease height
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FF2824" change do your desired color
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   />

<View
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FF2824"//change do your desired color
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Resulting snap shot.

[image]

Method 2

Here you are not using any new views. Just add a custom background to the existing layout. This will occupy less memory than the above coz you are not creating any new views.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bkg" //add custom background
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

create a drawable folder under resources and define bkg.xml under it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 
    </shape>
   </item>   
   <item android:top="20dp" android:bottom="20dp"   >  
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   </shape>
  </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

Comment: @prabu you can set the custom background to the layout. You need not have unnecessary layouts which will occupy memory.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<View
android:id="@+id/line_top" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dip"
android:background="#FF0000" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<View
android:id="@+id/line_bottom" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dip"
android:background="#FF0000" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```